# Where is the Bio.Alphabet _verify_alphabet function now located?

Tags: python, bioinformatics, biopython

Since `Bio.Alphabet` [recently](https://biopython.org/wiki/Alphabet) migrated in `Bio.Seq`, I would like to understand where the [_verify_alphabet](http://file:///tmp/mozilla_claudio0/Bio.Alphabet-module.html) function is now located.

I could also re-write entirely the function but since I am just updating an old python code I would prefer to use something already published.

Thank you for your support

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid `Bio.Alphabet` is not migrated, it was deprecated and now has been removed completely in Biopython 1.78. Here is the [old source code](https://github.com/biopython/biopython/blob/bfa6f93b7609b1f3fbefe02aefda7fa71d25596e/Bio/Alphabet/__init__.py#L490-L519) for `_verify_alphabet`. Fortunately, you can easily emulate the function:

```
def _verify_alphabet(sequence, alphabet):
    alphabet = set(alphabet) 
    return all(letter in alphabet for letter in sequence)

print(_verify_alphabet("AATGC", "ATCG"))
print(_verify_alphabet("AATUC", "ATCG"))
```